# yocto opendds does not create the sdknative files

Tags: yocto, bitbake, opendds, yocto-layer

I am trying to build an application that communicates with dds with opendds. I am using the opendds layer on krikstone. The bitbake image is built with the opendds libraries but when I build the sdk it seems the layer nativesdk is not installed. When I run the cmake I get the error "Missing required dependencies OPENDDS_IDL;ACE_GPERF;TAO_IDL".
from the opendds.inc I see there is the nativesdk install. I added a junk line and expected that when i build the opendds or build the populate-sdk I will fail but it seems that the nativesdk is not run.
build is for imx8mm variscite som with command bitbake fsl-image-qt5 -v populate_sdk_ext
layer with the problem is meta-opendds (krikstone branch) building version 3.22
the layer has a bb file that requires an opendds.inc file which has the nativesdk install

> Blockquote

do_install:append:class-nativesdk() {
***dfdf** -- my junk line to trigger failure*
ln -sf ${bindir}/opendds_idl ${D}${datadir}/dds/bin/opendds_idl
ln -sf ${bindir}/ace_gperf ${D}${datadir}/ace/bin/ace_gperf
ln -sf ${bindir}/tao_idl ${D}${datadir}/ace/bin/tao_idl
}

> Blockquote

** i added a junk line to trigger failure but it doesnt fail with building the sdk or image itself

why is the nativesdk command not run and why is the sdk without the opendds_idl executable
thanks

Comment: Can you provide more detailed steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: i am building imx8mm (variscite som) with command bitbake fsl-image-qt5 -c populate_sdk. The layer that i have a problem with is opendds running version 3.22. the bb file includes an opendds.inc file that has the nativesdk install command. " do_install:append:class-nativesdk() {
    dfdf  -- my junk to see if the command is run 
    ln -sf ${bindir}/opendds_idl ${D}${datadir}/dds/bin/opendds_idl
    ln -sf ${bindir}/ace_gperf ${D}${datadir}/ace/bin/ace_gperf
    ln -sf ${bindir}/tao_idl ${D}${datadir}/ace/bin/tao_idl
}
" ** i have added junk to see if the command fails but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I was able at last to build the nativesdk files. I had to build them specifically as they are not build by default. i had to "bitbake nativesdk-opendds" manually.
my mistake was to believe that the nativesdk will be defaulted. my assumption is that if i am using the opendds that most probable that i will build subscribers/produces applications and will need the opendds_idl executable.
!!!! after testing the nativesdk-opendds it did not solve the problem !!!
!! in general after adding building the opendds layer i cannot build the Messanger example for lack of the opendds_idl and other two (tao,ace) executable